# Prove that $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Is it necessary that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ such that, there is an $x \in X$ satisfying $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for every $f \in X^*$. Prove that $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Is it necessary that $(x_n)$ converges to $x$?

Require Hints for the problem.

Comment: Perhaps take $f \in X$ to be the identity function?

Comment: I also thought about that..

Comment: I just realised that the notation is a tad wrong, did you mean by $f \in X$ as $f:X \to X$?

Comment: Do you mean to have $f\in X^*$?

Comment: And I hope that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: f is in the dual space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the uniform boundedness principle. Recall that a convergent sequence of real/complex numbers is bounded.

Complete proof in spoiler:

> Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $X$ such that $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ for every $f\in X^*$. (This means that $x_n\to x$ weakly.) Thus for each $f\in X^*$, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ in $\mathbb{K}\in\{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}\}$ is convergent, and hence bounded. This means that $$\sup_n|f(x_n)|<\infty, \quad\text{for every $f\in X^*$.}$$ Using $J:X\to X^{**}$ for the canonical isometry defined by $(Jy)(f)=f(y)$ for every $y\in X$ and $f\in X^*$, we can reformulate the above as $$\sup_n|(Jx_n)(f)|<\infty, \quad\text{for every $f\in X^*$.}$$ Since $X^*$ is complete (beacuse $X^*=C(X,\mathbb{K})$), we can apply the uniform boundedness principle to conclude $\sup_n\|Jx_n\|<\infty$. This implies, by the fact that $J$ is an isometry (which can be proved using the Hahn-Banach theorem), that $\sup_n\|x_n\|<\infty$. Therefore $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence.

This does not imply that $x_n\to x$ in norm. Consider an orthonormal basis on an infinite dimensional Hilbert space as a counter example.
More details below:

> For instance, on $\ell^2$, take $(x_n)$ to be the standard orthonormal basis. Then, for every $f\in \ell^2$, we have $|\langle x_n, f \rangle| = |f(n)|$, which converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ (by definition of $\ell^2$). Hence $\langle x_n,f \rangle \to 0=\langle 0,f \rangle$, so that by the Rieze representation theorem, $x_n\to0$ weakly in $\ell^2$. However $x_n\not\to0$ in norm because $\|x_n\|=1$ for every $n$.

In fact, you can construct a similar sequence in any infinite dimensional reflexive space.